# Can't install Zabbix by apt-get - checksum error - Debian 9

Tags: debian, apt, zabbix

It is impossible to install Zabbix with apt-get install on my Debian 9.
I was following instructions on Zabbix page - I choose version 3.4 - Debian 9 - PostgreSQL but also 3.2, 3.0 LTS version or MySQL instead Postgres - no effect.
When I try to install Zabbix with command:

```
apt install zabbix-server-pgsql zabbix-frontend-php php-pgsql zabbix-agent
```

Then output looks like this (original output in polish - this is my translate):

```
(...)
incorrect checksum
  Hashes of expected file:
    SHA256: 2cd774 (...)
    MD5Sum: 2636bf (...)
    Filesize: 231550 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
    SHA256: 9214bd (...)ap
    MD5Sum: e4c0b (...)
    Filesize: 2438 [weak]
last modification reported: Tue, 30 Jan 2018, 17:04
E: Cannot download some files, please try apt-get update or --fix-missing option
```

Of-course apt-get update or --fix-missing not resolved problem.
My sources.list is standard (Polish Debian repositories) but I also tried US or even Australian test servers.

I tried

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and apt-get clean, update, upgrade etc. Nothing helped. Problem is only with zabbix-server-pgsql or zabbix-server-mysql. Other packages installed correctly.
The same problem is with 3.2 and 3.0 LTS version.

EDIT

I used following instruction before apt install:

```
 wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/debian/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_3.4-1+stretch_all.deb
 dpkg -i zabbix-release_3.4-1+stretch_all.deb
 apt update
```

Instructions from zabbix.com/download page. 
Moreover, I tried to install Zabbix on my test Debian 8 on VirtualBox and there is a problem too, but only information is after apt install is -

```
cannot download (...) libsnmp30 (...) - wrong size
```

**SOLVED** - 
Fortigate firewall blocked libsnmp30 package - even if I want download it from web browser from Debian repositories. I downloaded it by proxy, install package by dpkg and it works.

Comment: Which exact instructions did you follow and what commands did you run prior to `apt install`?

Comment: @Richlv I used following instruction before apt install:
`# wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/debian/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_3.4-1+stretch_all.deb'
'# dpkg -i zabbix-release_3.4-1+stretch_all.deb'
'# apt update`
Instructions from zabbix.com/download page. 
Moreover, I tried to install Zabbix on my test Debian 8 on VirtualBox and there is a problem too, but only information is after apt install is - cannot download (...) libsnmp30 (...) - wrong size

Comment: Please put that information ↑ in your question. It's important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! There was a problem with firewall / router which blocked the libsnmp30 package. I downloaded it manually and installed with dpkg.